# Page updates, when I try to send mail-foem data by using ajax+php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, email

I am trying to send data by using ajax technology. I made an ajax_form.js file, that responsible for this function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("email").val();
    var message = $("message").val();
$("#push").submit(function(e){  // $("#push") is a button
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "../send.php",
        tpye: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: { 'name': name, 'email': email, 'message': message },
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#push").prop("disabled",true);
        },
        succsess: function(data){
            if(!data){
                alert("ошибка при отправке данных");
            }
            else{
                $("#mail_form").trigger("reset");
                alert(data);    
            }
            
            $("push").prop("disabled", false);
        },
    })
    
})
})
```

I made the following script send.php, that contain variables and mail() function for sending:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode("Заявка с сайта")."?=";
$headers = "From: $email\r\nReply to: $email\r\nContent-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";



$name = trim($name);
$name = trim($email);

if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($message)){
    $success = mail("d.romanuk@mail.ru", $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo $success;
}
ini_set("display_errors","1");
ini_set("display_startup_errors","1");
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

Thisa is my html-form:

```
<form id="mail_form" class="mail__form" action="" id="send" method="post" name="form">
                    <label class="mail__label">
                        ИМЯ:
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="mail__input" id="name"type="text" name="name" placeholder="ИМЯ" required>
                    <br>
                    <label class="mail__label">
                        E-MAIL:
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="mail__input" type="mail" name="email" id="email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required>
                    <br>
                    <label class="mail__label">
                        СООБЩЕНИЕ:
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="mail__message" required>
                        
                    </textarea>
                    <br>
                    <button id="push" type="submit" class="mail__button">
                        ОТПРАВИТЬ
                    </button>

                </form>
```

Here I have two problems:
1)When I click the button, the page is updated, and data from the mail form does not send; it should not update web page because I am using `e.preventDefault()`
2)And I suppose that my web-form doesn't work, because it should be `alert()` after sending data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit events are fired on **form** elements, but you are attaching your event listener to a **button**.

Move it to the form.

Comment: What do you mean? In this case, button 
element is a part of form elements.

Comment: `$(this_needs_to_be_the_form_not_the_button).submit(...)`

Comment: Ok, but If I don't mistake, data from form will be sent after clicking on the form, not on the button.

Comment: Clicking on a form doesn't do anything. Clicking on a submit button will submit *a form*.